# Design Question Kafka Consumer/Producer vs Kafka Stream

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm working with NodeJs MS, so far they communicate through Kafka Consumer/Producer. Now I need to buiid a Loggger MS which must record all the messages and do some processing (parse and save to db), but I'm not sure if the  current approach could be improved using Kafka Stream or if I should continue using Consumers

Comment: The answer to this question probably depends on what 'do some processing' actually means. Can you share more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Streams API is a higher level abstraction that sits on top of the Consumer/Producer APIs. The Streams API allows you to filter and transform messages, and build a topology of processing steps.

For what you're describing, if you're just picking up a messages and doing a single processing step, the Consumer API is probably fine. That said, you could do the same thing with the Streams API too and not use the other features.

Comment: Kafka Streams is in Java, though

Answer (score 1):

> buiid a Loggger MS which must record all the messages and do some processing (parse and save to db)

I would suggest using something like Streams API or Nodejs Producer + Consumer to parse and *write back to Kafka*.

From your parsed/filtered/sanitized messages, you can run a *Kafka Connect cluster* to sink your data into a DB

> could be improved using Kafka Stream or if I should continue using Consumers

Ultimately, depends what you need. The `peek` and `foreach`  methods of Streams DSL are functionally equivalent to a Consumer